# Loading select options with style and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/V6Tfc/2/). I am trying to find out why I am not able to load the Select Options into the selection list correctly.

Here is the code which I am using to update the selections based on user clicks

```
// Initial settign for load 
$( ".selectpicker" ).selectpicker();

// Loading From The First Table
$("#loader1").on("click",function(){
    $(".selectpicker").html('<option value="0">Select From The List</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">Option 1- 1</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">Option 1- 2</option>'+
                            '<option value="3">Option 1- 3</option>'
                           )
    $( ".selectpicker" ).selectpicker("refresh");
});

// Loading From The Second Table
$("#loader2").on("click",function(){
    $(".selectpicker").html('<option value="0">Select From The List</option>'+
                            '<option value="4">Option 1- 1</option>'+
                            '<option value="5">Option 1- 2</option>'+
                            '<option value="6">Option 1- 3</option>'
                           )
    $( ".selectpicker" ).selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you code has it or not, but you don't have semicolons after your `.html()` calls.  Could that be your issue?

Comment: If I were you, I'd keep it simple by just having two select pickers within your HTML with unique ID's, and just hide and show whichever one you want.

Comment: Also, what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Hi , I am using Bootstrap v3.1.1, I  have many tables in this scenario so I do not want to have a big long code for each table and selection list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

[Bootstrap Select Picker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/) actually just uses the `select` element as a reference. View your source and you will see that the plugin actually hides the `select` and creates an entire new section in a `div` with a `button`.

Therefore, your problem is, the plugin is also copying over your classes aswel, and replacing its contents. Give it an ID, and it will work perfectly.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<select id="selectPicker" class="form-control selectClass" data-container="body" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0">Select From The List</option>
</select>
```

**Updated jQuery:**

```
    // Loading From The First Table
$("#loader1").on("click", function () {
    $("#selectPicker").html('<option value="0">Select From The List</option><option value="1">Option 1- 1</option><option value="2">Option 1- 2</option><option value="3">Option 1- 3</option>');
    $(".selectClass").selectpicker("refresh");
});

// Loading From The Second Table
$("#loader2").on("click", function () {
    $("#selectPicker").html('<option value="0">Select From The List</option><option value="4">Option 2- 1</option><option value="5">Option 2- 2</option><option value="6">Option 2- 3</option>');
    $(".selectClass").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Tfc/10/)

### Solution 2

Although, you could keep it simple and just hide or show which ever option list you would like displayed, like so:

**Updated jQuery:**

```
// Show first list
$("#loader1").on("click", function () {
    $(".selectpicker1").show();
    $(".selectpicker2").hide();
});

// Show second list
$("#loader2").on("click", function () {
    $(".selectpicker2").show();
    $(".selectpicker1").hide();
});
```

Although, I will continue to work on the solution you asked for in your original question.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Tfc/9/)

Comment: Thanks fizzix, but as I already told you I have a big bunch of list from database. it is not only two! Besides even in your example the <select> is not taking care of the Bootstrap-select plugin which is my main problem

Comment: Check out 'Solution 1'. Fixes your problem :)

Comment: I think you are missing the Bootstrap-select plugin part http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: I do not have any issue on loading data, my problem is loading the options WITH bootstrap-select plugin

Comment: So what is your problem EXACTLY?

Comment: Because in your data, the options are not loading at all when either button is clicked. But in my Solution 1, I fixed this issue, and the options are loading perfectly.

Comment: so why I am not seeing them in Bootstrap-select format!

Comment: I have made an edit to both solutions and they are now both using the correct Bootstrap Select Plugin styles and formats.